# XML Drawable Producing Wrong Background

Tags: android, xml

I have a weird issue with one XML Drawable

On my Galaxy Nexus Phone (API 17), the drawable looks like this which is correct.

[image]

However on an older phone (HTC Explorer) (2.3.5 Gingerbread) it looks like this which is wrong

[image]

This is my XML drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FF0000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="3dp" />

</shape>
```

And the text view

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSet1One"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="01"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Note that the background of the text view Is set in Java via the setBackgroundResource method.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a transparent background (using solid) to your shape in the drawable xml. On newer Android versions the background defaults to transparent, but on older ones it defaults to black.

So your XML drawable would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FF0000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="3dp" />

    <solid
        android:color="#00000000"/>

</shape>
```